# Same app/same code has half a volume on iPhone compared to iPad, WHY?

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, openal

I'm using OpenAL, location, and gain values just the same.
Any similar experiences?

Comment: Because it depends on the device itself. It's not stated anywhere an absolute value like in decibels but relative ones from low to high.

Comment: Whoa, thanks, but what is the solution of the problem?

Comment: Adjust some system volume whatever?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the iPhone has a less powerful speaker than the iPad.

Nothing to do with your code whatsoever.

Comment: It is far more silent. Other Apps just doin' well.

Comment: @Geri try it with headphones - also as a slightly pedantic side note, something can't be 'more silent', it's either silent or it isn't.

Comment: Wioth headphones it has the same volume as other apps, but without, it is much more silent compared to other apps.

Comment: Ye, I haven't find the righ word. Less loud. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is about **the sound category of AVAudio session**.
When it is AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient, or AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, then it was low, but **setting it to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback** solved the problem.